# Why not always makes sense to generalize the square metric $\rho$ to $\mathbb {R}^{\omega}$?

Tags: general-topology

In page 124 of Munkers Topology, it says

> One can attempt to generalize the square metric $\rho$ to $\mathbb {R}^{\omega}$ by defining $$\rho({\bf x},{\bf y})=\sup{|{\bf x}_n - {\bf y}_n|}$$ but this formula does not always makes sense.

I don't understand why "this formula does not always make sense". Especially, according to the Completeness Axiom if the points are not infinitely far so the supremum always exists.

Is there any simple example so I can understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the two points $x=(0,0,0,\dots)$ and $y=(0,1,2,3\dots)$. What is $\rho(x,y)$?

Comment: Yes, I got it! Thanks. But why it makes sense for $\rho(x,y)$ to define on $\mathbb R^n$ even if the two pts are infinitely apart? Why a 'distance' in a metric on $\mathbb R^n$ can be $\infty$ but it can't be $\infty$ for $\mathbb R^{\omega}$?

Comment: A "distance" in a metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ *must not* be $\infty$. A distance function must satisfy $0 \le \rho(x,y) < \infty$.

Comment: @Liebe in a finite dimensional setting there is no need for a sup even, we take a maximum of finitely many differences. Only for infinite dimensional spaces we need a supremum, even for bounded sequences, e.g. consider $0$ and $(1-\frac{1}{n})_n$, but the $\sup$ also need not exist. Finite-dimensional the $\infty$ problem does not occur.

Comment: @Liebe In $\Bbb R^n$ there are no two points with $\rho(x,y)=\infty$. The two points in my example are not points in $\Bbb R^n$. (What two points did you have in mind?)

Comment: I thought that one point be at the origin and the other at infinity.

Comment: @Liebe Infinity is not a point of $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is only that some points in $\mathbb R^\omega$ are infinitely far apart according to this metric.

This is the space of sequences of real numbers.  Consider two sequences:
\begin{align}
0,\,0,\,0,\,0,\,0,\,0,\,\ldots \\
1,\,2,\,3,\,4,\,5,\,6,\,\ldots
\end{align}
The distance between them is
$$
\sup\{ |1-0|, |2-0|, |3-0|, |4-0|, \ldots \} = \infty.
$$
By definition of "metric", the distance must be a member of $\mathbb R$; thus a finite number.